# How to re-order the code in order to get correct iteration counter

Tags: python, iteration, counter

Here is the piece of code where I need to return correct index which should be decreased by 1 on each iteration according to 'else' section:

```
def findBestShift(wordList, text):

    splited_text = text.split(' ')
    index=26

    while index >= 0:
        for item in splited_text:
            if item in wordList:
                return index # in this place I need to get decreased index depends on the amount of iterations, instead of 26 which I always get
            else:
                index-=1
                return findBestShift(wordList,applyShift(item,index))
```

How to re-order the code in order to return decreased index? Except this little issue for me the code works ok.

The purpose of this code is to decrypt a string by this method -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher.

We have some encoded words, then trying to decode them by shifting letters in alphabet and comparing words with a wordList.

If decoded word matches a word from wordList - we need to return number (shift), 
if words does not match each other then shifting (decreasing) alphabet by 1 letter more and compare words again.

Comment: Your function is both iterative and recursive. I don't know what you are trying to do but generally it is iterative or recursive but not both of them...

Comment: The problem is that right after index is decremented findBestShift() is returned which sets index=26 when it executes.  This could be fixed by making index an argument of findBestShift()  or making it global by initializing it before and outside of findBestShift().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize index to be 26 out of "findBestShift" and pass it as a parameter to findBestShift